# How to use *ngFor on grouped items in a slider?

Tags: angular

I have a slider with groups of items like this:

```
<-- Group 1 -->
<div class="group">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 0-4
</div>

<-- Group 2 -->
<div class="group">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 5-10
</div>

<-- Group 3 -->
<div class="group">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 11-15
</div>
```

How do I achieve this with the Angular *ngFor directive?

Comment: You should delegate any data manipulation to the controller and leave the template to just render. Split the elements into groups of 5 and pass each to the template.

Comment: I am using Angular 13 and pretty new to it. Could give an illustrative code example?

Comment: @99JS , is this `group` an array?

Comment: No, the groups is just an abstraction. The items however is an array of items from n....N coming from a service. In other words, I do not know how long the array of items is but I still need to group the items in groups of 5 items per group.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yh58b?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <-- Group 1 -->
<div class="group" *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:4">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 0-4
</div>

<-- Group 2 -->
<div class="group" *ngFor="let item of items | slice:5:10">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 5-10
</div>

<-- Group 3 -->
<div class="group" *ngFor="let item of items | slice:11:15">
   <div class="element"> // <---- I want this to contain elements 11-15
</div>
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Comment: Here is an example that shows what I am trying to achieve:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yh58b?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you need three array data segregate from the parent array, that you need to manipulate the data from the parent array to the controller `.ts` and then render it in `.html`. Check the below code,

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pebwzt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
  data1;
  data2;
  data3;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data1 = this.data.slice(0, 5);
    this.data2 = this.data.slice(5, 11);
    this.data3 = this.data.slice(11);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h3>First Array</h3>
<div *ngFor="let d1 of data1">
  <div>{{ d1 }}</div>
</div>
<h3>Second Array</h3>
<div *ngFor="let d2 of data2">
  <div>{{ d2 }}</div>
</div>
<h3>Third Array</h3>
<div *ngFor="let d3 of data3">
  <div>{{ d3 }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Aniruddh, this is a very good and pragmatic approach. I forgot to mention that the items is part of an array of items from n....N coming from a service. In other words, I do not know how long the array of items is but I still need to group the items in groups of 5 items per group. How to best adapt the above code to fit such requirements?

Comment: Can you provide me with one `stackblitz` demo example to check how is your JSON formatted so I can guide you a better way.

Comment: Hi Aniruddh,
I am using Google Books API to fetch information about books. Each div (w/ class element) is a card showing the book picture and title. Then I use a css grid to put the books in a row with overflow hidden. What I want to do is bind a click event to an arrow that scrolls 1 group to the right (i.e. 5 books).

I am using this code describe in this youtube video [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yfswsnD2sw)

Comment: Here is a Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yh58b?file=src/app/app.component.html

It does not have the service but the idea would be the same, I get the images and book titles from Google Books and display them using the same HTML and CSS as in the Stackblitz example above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. You are presenting just `div`'s with class `element` where are the mentioned sliders? What type of data structure is "groups"? For more details you need to present some more info.

Anyway here is an possible example, how you could use `*ngFor` to generate the `div`'s.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = [...Array(16).keys()];
  groups = [...Array(3).keys()];
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
  <div class="group">
    Group: {{group}}
     <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
      <div class="element" *ngIf="item < 5 && group == 0">Element: {{item}}</div>
      <div class="element" *ngIf="item > 5 && item < 11 && group == 1">Element: {{item}}</div>
      <div class="element" *ngIf="item > 9 && group == 2">Element: {{item}}</div>
     </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
Group: 0
Element: 0
Element: 1
Element: 2
Element: 3
Element: 4
Group: 1
Element: 6
Element: 7
Element: 8
Element: 9
Element: 10
Group: 2
Element: 10
Element: 11
Element: 12
Element: 13
Element: 14
Element: 15
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-efxd9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi Joosep,

Thank you for your reply. In hindsight my question was not that clear. I will make sure to include Stackblitz examples going forward.
Here is one that shows the slider that I am trying to integrate in my Angular project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7yh58b?file=src/app/app.component.html